# Microsoft Azure Multi-Factor and NetScaler

Tags: azure, netscaler

Does anyone have any examples on configuring Azure Multi-Factor Authentication and NetScaler VPX 10.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is relatively easy.

We are using the Multi-Factor authentication for a NetScaler Gateway.

Simply create a server
add authentication radiusAction 'servername' -serverIP 1.2.3.4 -authTimeout 30 -radKey thisistheecryptedkey -encrypted

And a Policy...
add authentication radiusPolicy MFA ns_true 'servername'

And apply this to the MF Server.
On the Server, be sure to create a Radius client - IP, Application Name, Shared Secret.

Comment: I was trying to use LDAP, but I couldn't get that to work.  Using RADIUS I was able to configure NetScaler VPX to use Azure Multi-Factor for remote access.

Thanks!